# Does bulk insert task override the database recovery model?

Tags: ssis

Bulk Insert Task

> Inserts data from file into table with minimal logging.

The logging is usually decided by the database recovery model - for example full vs bulk logged recovery model.

Does the bulk insert task override the database recovery model? Otherwise how can it perform minimal logging?

Comment: Where do you get this quote from? Is it from the official documentation?

Comment: Yes this is from official Microsoft ebook for exam 70767 implementing sql warehouse